# Setting cookie expire time in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am building an API with Sails.js. For session storage I am using redis. Fun stuff!

The Set-Cookie Response Header contains

```
sails.sid=<sessionID>; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Simple thing in an express application, but I am having a hard time on how to set the expires value for that Cookie. Does anyone know?

Setting ttl for redis does not have any effect by the way.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer to the above question myself. Just add

```
cookie: {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000  // example: 60 mins in miliseconds
}
```

to your sails.js config/session.js file.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Where did you find this? Can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Not sure anymore. I think by inspecting the sails.js code.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is running behind proxy/ revserse proxy ( nginx) and you want to set a secure flag to your cookie just modify:

**config/session.js** and add these lines:

```
proxy: true,
cookie: {
  secure: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your controller to set cookie expire time

`res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true });`